# How can I slice a numpy array into another numpy array of different size?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm trying to broadcast the contents of one array into another array like this:

```
A = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4]])
A_broadcast = np.array([[1, 0, 3, 0], [0, 2, 0, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

My current approach is by initializing `A_broadcast` with `np.zeros((3, 4))` and slicing the contents of `A` into `A_broadcast` one line at a time like this:

```
A_broadcast[::2][0] = A[0]
A_broadcast[1::2][1] = A[1]
A_broadcast[::2][2] = A[0]
A_broadcast[1::2][2] = A[1]
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (4,)` This approach works in Matlab so I thought something similar would work here. Is there a way this approach can work? If not, what could I do to get a similar effect?

Comment: You have the index order wrong. `A_broadcast[0][::2] = A[0]` or in one go `A_broadcast[0,::2] = A[0]`

Comment: often it's a good idea to test the LHS by itself..  `A_broadcast[::2][0]` what's that shape?  The error says (4,)?  The ::2 selects everyother row, that is 2: (2,4).  The [0] selects one of those, hence (4,).

Comment: Thank you @Julien! Oops, such a simple error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 arrays:

```
In [86]: A = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4]])
    ...: A_broadcast = np.array([[1, 0, 3, 0], [0, 2, 0, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
  
In [88]: A
Out[88]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [89]: A_broadcast
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

the blank:

```
In [87]: res = np.zeros((3,4),int)
```

The first row of `A` goes into a square that alternates in both directions:

```
In [90]: res[::2,::2]=A[0]

In [91]: res
Out[91]: 
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Actually I wasn't sure if `A[0]` was right its (2,1) version.  I could have analzed the case, but instead just tried it.  Sometimes in an interactive session it's easier to try a few alternatives than to carefully work out the details in my head before hand. It's easy to experient in an interactive session with modules like numpy.

Now it's easy to do the same with the 2nd row,

```
In [92]: res[1:,1::2]=A[1]

In [93]: res
Out[93]: 
array([[1, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Nothing wrong with indexing the target one row at a time as you attempt:

```
In [94]: res[0,::2]
Out[94]: array([1, 3])

In [95]: res[2,1::2]
Out[95]: array([2, 4])
```

Both rows could also be indexed with advanced indexing - we just have to get the broadcasting right, using a (2,1), and (2,) arrays (or list equivalents):

```
In [96]: res[[[0],[2]],[0,2]]
Out[96]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [1, 3]])

In [97]: res[[[1],[2]],[1,3]]
Out[97]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach can be improved by using NumPy's array manipulation and broadcasting capabilities. Here's a more efficient way to achieve the desired result:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4]])
rows, cols = A.shape

# Create a mask to insert zeros at appropriate positions
mask = np.zeros((rows * 2, cols * 2), dtype=bool)
mask[::2, ::2] = True

# Create the broadcasting array with zeros
A_broadcast = np.zeros((rows * 2, cols * 2))

# Use the mask to assign values from array A to A_broadcast
A_broadcast[mask] = A.flatten()

print("Original Array A:")
print(A)
print("Broadcasted Array A_broadcast:")
print(A_broadcast)
```

This code creates a mask that will insert values from array A at the specified positions in A_broadcast. It then flattens A and uses the mask to assign the values to the corresponding positions in the broadcasting array. The result is the desired broadcasting effect.

Here's the output:

```
Original Array A:
[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
Broadcasted Array A_broadcast:
[[1. 0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 4.]
 [1. 0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0. 4.]]
```

This approach avoids the need for separate assignments for each row and uses broadcasting efficiently to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Is there any way to use a mask to get the desired behavior in the third row of A_broadcast?